# Focused input field obscured by virtual keyboard

Tags: html, css, mobile, touch, firefox-os

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<body style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 420px;">
</body>
```

See image sequence below, from left to right:

1. Page freshly loaded.
2. Input field focused. It gets obscured by the virtual keyboard.
3. Only once the user starts typing, the input field becomes visible.

Removing `overflow: hidden` makes the input field visible right on focus, which I consider to be more user friendly.

*Is there a way to specify hidden overflow for the body, and not have the virtual keyboard obscure the focused input field?*

[image: Sequence of screenshots of Firefox OS simulator]

Answer (score 1):

i solved obscured inputs by the on screen keyboard with scrolling page by an animate

```
    var headerHeight = $("header").outerHeight(true);
    $(document).on('focus', 'input:not([name=option]),select,textarea', function (e) {
        $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(e.target).offset().top - (headerHeight + 30) }, 500);
    });
```

also you can use these features

[scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
[scrollIntoViewIfNeeded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded)